# How to display field in .json file across multiple lines

Tags: json, formatting

Hey guys I have a json file **connections.json** with the following airflow connections

```
{
    "google_cloud_default": {
      "conn_type": "google_cloud_platform",
      "host": null,
      "login": null,
      "password": null,
      "schema": null,
      "port": null,
      "extra": "{\"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path\": \"/usr/local/sample_path/credentials/sample.json\", \"extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries\": 5, \"extra__google_cloud_platform__project\": \"sample-project\", \"extra__google_cloud_platform__scope\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets\"}"
    }

}
```

Is it possible to extend the "extra" parameter so it spans multiple lines for readability?

Like so:

```
    {
    "google_cloud_default": {
      "conn_type": "google_cloud_platform",
      "host": null,
      "login": null,
      "password": null,
      "schema": null,
      "port": null,
      "extra": "{\"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path\": \"/usr/local/sample_path/credentials/sample.json\", 
               \"extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries\": 5,
              \"extra__google_cloud_platform__project\": \"sample-project\", 
              \"extra__google_cloud_platform__scope\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets\"}"
    }

}
```

I tried wrapping the entire `extra` value in three double quotes i.e. `"""` but that still seems to throw an error. Thoughts?

Comment: your json is invalid. pls post the real one

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by the real one. This IS my connections.json file.

Comment: I mean extra property is a string, not a json

Comment: Yes, this is valid for it's purpose. For airflow to read in the 'extra' parameters, it has to be wrapped as a string. If not, it throughs a JSON decode error when I run the DAG.